# ArrayList<JButton> adding Action listeners with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener

Been stuck on this for awhile now and thought after a bit of searching and not finding what I'm looking for would ask to see if anyone has a solution to my problem. Currently for a small collage project I'm working on I need to have a panel which contains 100 buttons but each button must have an action listener. This action listener when selected must report its number in the grid and change the text of the button.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) //Sets buttons created
    {
        ArrayList<JButton> testButton = new ArrayList<JButton>(); //Button Text
        PlayerGrid1.add( new JButton(" ? ") );
    }
```

The Code is how I add the buttons to the ArrayList but the issue I'm having is when I try to add an action listener it throws errors about abstract buttons and other issues.

```
JPanel PlayerGrid1 = new JPanel();
    PlayerGrid1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    PlayerGrid1.setBounds(0, 0, 375, 400);
    frmBattleships.getContentPane().add(PlayerGrid1);
    PlayerGrid1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 0, 0));
```

This is the grid in which I store the Buttons.

If anyone one knows how I can add a listener to the ArrayList or has a link to a post of someone using the same method as me it would be appreciated. Also just to let anyone know if this is not set out correctly or wrong please don't flame I don't normally ask many Stack overflow Questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a map instead of list before **for loop** like:

```
Map<String,JButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String,JButton>();
```

After that you should set unique action command for each button in **for loop** 'i' can be used for that purpose.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) //Sets buttons created
{
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              buttonMap.get(e.getActionCommand()).setText("Whatever you want!");
            }
        });
buttonMap.put(String.valueOf(i), button);
PlayerGrid1.add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `

```
    JFrame frmBattleships = new JFrame();
    JPanel PlayerGrid1 = new JPanel();
    PlayerGrid1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    PlayerGrid1.setBounds(0, 0, 375, 400);
    frmBattleships.getContentPane().add(PlayerGrid1);
    PlayerGrid1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) // Sets buttons created
    {
        ArrayList<JButton> testButton = new ArrayList<JButton>(); // Button
        JButton newButton = new JButton("" + i); // Text
        newButton.setName("" + i);
        newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getName());

            }
        });
        PlayerGrid1.add(newButton);

    }
    frmBattleships.setVisible(true);

`
```